# Find and set css to html element in variable

Tags: jquery

Suppose i have variable in js and that variable has html as text
like

```
sHtml = "<div id='dvPrint' ><table>";
sHtml += "<tr><td>" + "<img src='" + ImgPath + "' height='900' width='600' border='0'/>" + "</td></tr>";
sHtml += "<tr><td>" + $('#lblTxt').html() + "</td></tr>";
sHtml += "</table></div>";
```

So how could I set css to img element by jquery because it is stored in js variable.

### can i set css in the below way

```
sHtml = "<div id='dvPrint'><table>";
sHtml += "<tr><td>" + "<img src='" + ImgPath + "' border='0'/>" + "</td></tr>";
sHtml += "<tr><td>" + $('#lblTxt').html() + "</td></tr>";
sHtml += "</table></div>";
var $dvPrint = $(sHtml);
$dvPrint.addClass('imageCss');
```

plzz tell me is there anything wrong. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#dvPrint img').css()` - http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: i edit my code so plzz have look it will work now? one more question that how to find & extract only image from variable. plzz guide.

Answer (score 0):

try  below with **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**

```
   $( '#dvPrint > img ').live ('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('imageCss');
    });
```

**Note:** you must be adding that `sHTml` on an event, so you can write that event instead of `click` in above code

Comment: i edit my code so plzz have look it will work now? one more question that how to find & extract only image from variable. plzz guide

Answer (score 0):

If the img element has been outputted to the page, then you can select it and assign a class using Javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myimg");
elem.className = "my_css_class";
```

You need to give the image an ID or some other way of being able to locate it though. There's lots of ways of doing that including walking the DOM.

If it hasn't been outputted to the page, and is just sitting in a Javascript variable, then edit the variable.

Answer (score 0):

That HTML has to be put into the DOM in order to jQuery can work with it. Or you can use it as XML in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a style attribute when you build up your HTML, eg.

```
sHtml += "<img style=\""+  ImgCss +"\" src=\"" + ImgPath + "\" />";
```

Comment: i edit my code so plzz have look it will work now? one more question that how to find & extract only image from variable. plzz guide.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use DOM's API ?

```
 var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
 $(newDiv).html('your html');
 $(newDiv).addClass('whatever');
```

okay, misread the question, but I think answer may still apply.
Create the `img` node with create element then insert into `div` element via DOM.

Comment: i edit my code so plzz have look it will work now? one more question that how to find & extract only image from variable. plzz guide

Answer (score 0):

You can't effectively use jQuery nor any other JavaScript solution to apply a css class to the `<img>` element, as long as it is just inserted into a string and is not actively part of the DOM.

You could eventually obtain the behaviour you're looking for using jQuery's `.live()` API, but  you have to bound it to an event; that way you're guaranteed that even if your `<img>` element doesn't exist within the DOM initially, whenever it should be added it would automatically be bound to the event declared in `.live()` invocation, resulting (when the event fires) in the execution of the code which is interesting to you.
If this kind of scenario matches your requirements, then I suggest following the approach indicated by diEcho in this thread.

If, conversely, you only need to apply a css class or attribute to the `<img>` element in your string, you have 2 options only:

1) When your `<img>` element still lives only into your sHtml string, you can insert in it the correct css attribute, so whenever you will add sHtml content to the DOM, the image will be there with the correct css styles already;

2) When you already added sHtml content to the DOM, you can use a jQuery selector just like

```
$("#dvPrint > img").attr("class", "yourCssClass");
```

and it should do the job.

Hth.

Comment: i edit my code so plzz have look it will work now? one more question that how to find & extract only image from variable. plzz guide.